# how to use find method on an array that contains coordinates pair?

Tags: javascript, arrays, find

I have this class as follow. x and y are 2d coordinates

```
class Vector {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

i have a array to store coordinates x and y

```
const coordinatesStorage = [];

coordinatesStorage.push(new Vector(1, 2));
coordinatesStorage.push(new Vector(3, 4));
coordinatesStorage.push(new Vector(4, 6));
```

I want to find if there exists a coordinate (3,4) in coordinatesStorage array

```
if ( coordinatesStorage.find(Vector{x:3, y:4}) ) {
    gameOver = true;
}     // this code does not work
```

unfortunately the above mentioned is my lame approach that is invalid and is returning a Console error.
I have a C++ background. I am trying to convert my Cpp code to JS.

please help with that code **to find if there exists a coordinate (3,4) in coordinatesStorage array**

Comment: Good questions with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find` function on an array receives a function as its first parameter. That function receives a reference to an element in the array which you then have to return `true` or `false` for. If you want the `find` function to return that element as the found element, you return `true`. For you example, something like this should work:

```
if (coordinatesStorage.find(v => v.x === 3 && v.y === 4)) {
```

This states that it should return the first element in your `coordinatesStorage` where the element's `x` property is `3` and its `y` is `4`.

Note, the `v =>` part is the start of an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) where `v` is a parameter of the function that represents an element that's being tested in your array. It could alternatively be expanded to a regular function definition like this:

```
function vectorPredicate(vector) {
    return vector.x === 3 && vector.y === 4;
}
```

You could then pass that function defined into the `find` call too and it would work the same way:

```
if (coordinatesStorage.find(vectorPredicate)) {
```

Check out MDN's article on [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for more detailed information.

Comment: It's similar to a function pointer in C++. In this case, it's a function which will cause `find` to return the first element in the array that returns `true` for the function. `find` will return `undefined` if none of the elements tested with that function return `true`.